# How would I handle multiple sockets and send data between them in Python 2.7.3?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to create a server in Python 2.7.3 which sends data to all client connections whenever one client connection sends data to the server.  For instance, if client c3 sent `"Hello, world!"` to my server, I would like to then have my server send `"Hello, world!"` to client connections c1 and c2.  By client connections, I mean the communications sockets returned by `socket.accept()`.  <strike>Note that I have tried using the `asyncore` and `twisted` modules, but AFAIK they do not support this.</strike>  Does anybody know any way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**: I have seen Twisted, but I would much rather use the `socket` module.  Is there a way (possibly multithreading, possibly using select) that I can do this using the socket module?

Comment: would You consider using co-routines for single socket operation and then periodically get data from each socket and send necessary data to each socket.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do this using Twisted Python.  You just accept the connections and set up your own handling logic (of course the library does not including built-in support for your particular communication pattern exactly, but you can't expect that).